# How to Store SQLcipher password locally

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher-android

I'm working on an application which uses SQLcipher and it's offline, So its not possible for me to fetch Key from server to communicate with encrypted database.I have to store it securely somewhere within the device. One solution would be to store key in preference but if the phone is rooted on can gain access to these folders. Data used in application are highly confidential and I cannot let that get accessed. Would be great if you recommend things to sort this case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conceal library by facebook for the same.

https://facebook.github.io/conceal/

Comment: @Arunkarthick Nallasami I hope this might helps you.